# How to connect laravel api with pure html website

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, api, laravel-api

Since I am new to laravel api, I don't know hot to connect laravel api to html endpoint. My laravel api is working well and html web pages also completely finish. I just want to connect them together... Please explain how to connect these two.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two ways to go about this but it all depends on what your API does. If you are looking to serve the HTML with Laravel and have some parts of the application loaded by Laravels view() method, you'd basically need to break your HTML into blade files in resources/view folder and call the blade files via view() in controller to load the desired page.

However if you are looking for a separation of view and API where API is called by the view only for some information, you'd need to utilize AJAX via JavaScript to make a call to the API endpoint and retrieve the data (JSON) for use in your HTML site.

I use axios a lot and here is a sample call:

```
axios.get(url).then(response => { // do whatever here with the response data });
```

Comment: There also is the issue of API authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you. But it reads like you developed your Laravel Application (PHP) and HTML separately. Laravel uses Blade (see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade) as a template engine into which you can inject PHP objects. Basically, the call of a web page (more or less) works like this:

1. The user is calling the url
2. URL goes to the routes/web.php
3. in this file you can call e.g. a controller
4. the controller called via (e.g.)

   return view('my.site.nice-site', [ key => value]);
5. blade starts and displays the page to the user with the given key as variable.

I hope this helps you a bit. Otherwise I recommend, just to get started, the documentation from Laravel or YouTube.